# how to fetch the route i.e path of my current api in routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rail. I have few clarifications, which I have listed below.

1. I have referred many links and stack overflow questions, everywhere it's mentioned to use **request** and fetch the details regarding the *path, controller, action* etc. but if I use request in my routes.rb it throws **undefined local variable or method** error.
2. I used **constraints** in my **routes.rb** and from there it calls a method **matches?** from a class where dynamic constraints are defined inside *lib/constraints* directory. In here the **matches?(request)** receives a parameter named request, which has details about current route, from where the parameter value is sent?, I have this doubt because while using this method inside routes.rn in **constraint(ClassName)** I'm not sepecifying the method name **(matches?)** or the parameter **request**

I would like to know the working of things behind the scene.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for it

```
request.url
# => "http://localhost:3000/lists/7/items"
request.path
# => "/lists/7/items"
```

Comment: no, **Rails.application.routes.routes** this one gives list of all routes, my question is instead of getting all route how to fetch the route of my **current url**  in **routes.rb**

Comment: HI @NarayananV where do you want to fetch it ? at controller at any action?

Comment: I need to fetch at **routes.rb**, as mentioned in question **1.** I referred few stack questions, it instructed me to use **request.path** but it threw me an undefined variable error, Is there any other way to get the url path in routes.rb?

Comment: @NarayananV I can't get you, it would be better if you can show an example what are you looking for.

Comment: the same way I tried to access in routes.rb it threw me *NameError* undefined variable or method request

Comment: @NarayananV for example your current url is `localhost:300/users/sign_up` and you are searching for it's details in routes.rb then at console in project directory you try search something like this `rake routes | grep sign_up`

Comment: `request.path` or `request.url` can be used at any action not in `routes.rb`

Comment: yes, thanks. now my question is what is the equivalent command of ```request.path``` (which gives the current path) to be used in routes.rb?

Comment: @NarayananV Why would you use such command in your routes.rb?

Answer (score 0):

If you have URIs:

```
localhost:3000/users/:id
localhost:3000/users
localhost:3000/users/new
....
```

You can do something like

```
rake routes | grep user
```

in order to get only those that contain `user` in its path name.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

conventionally you don't access the current path in the routes.rb, at least as how it seems you're asking to access it. There are a number of different matching methods and techniques used in the rails router that serve the utility I imagine your looking for.

Here's a link to the docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Can you share exactly why you want to access the curret route in the routes.rb file?